# Static variable Current in Application

Tags: java, android, static

I was finding myself frequently calling `getApplication()` and casting it as `MyApplication` so that I could call a method in `MyApplication`.  I decided to declare the static variable `Current` in `MyApplication` and set it in the constructor.  Now I don't have to do the casting.

Are there any pitfalls to taking this approach?

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {
    public static MyApplication Current;
    public MyApplication(){
        super();
        Current = this;
    }
    public void doSomething(){

    }
}

public class MyActivity extends ListActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        MyApplication.Current.doSomething();
    }
}
```

Below is, I think, the normal approach for getting the application and calling the method.

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {
    public void doSomething(){

    }
}

public class MyActivity extends ListActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        ((MyApplication)getApplication()).doSomething();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

With this solution there is a danger that somebody accidentally change `MyApplication.current` to `null` or an invalid reference.

I'd override the `getApplication` method in the `MyActivity` class with a [covariant return type](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariant_return_type):

```
@Override
public MyApplication getApplication() {
    return (MyApplication) super.getApplication();
}
```

---

According to the [Code Conventions for the Java Programming Language](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconv-138413.html), `Current` should be `current`.

Comment: Couldn't he also just put that getApplication() method on MyApplication, like MyApplication.getCurrent()?
Point, as you say, is to provide read only access to the instance.

Comment: I'm not too familiar with Android and I could imagine some situation when `super.getApplication()` returns a proxy or wrapper class instead of the direct reference to the `MyApplication` instance. I don't know it is possible or not. On the other hand, static fields usually makes testing harder, so I try to avoid them.

Comment: Well, in this case MyApplication is obviously intended to be a single instance, so changing the "Current" member to private and exposing a static getter shouldn't be an issue imho. But I don't know Android either, so add a pinch of salt. (aren't more or less all mobile apps single instanced?)